# Getting MSSQL JDBC with Tomcat to automatically reconnect after restart or network issue

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat

When we have a MSSQL database failover, restart or network problem, it seems that we have to restart Tomcat5 to get it to reconnect to the database.  We are using the standard sqljdbc.jar with Java 1.5.  Can anyone tell me how to get it to automatically reconnect on a failure or outage so we don't have to manually restart our application each time this happens?

Here is what our server.xml looks like:

```
          <Resource name="jdbc/someDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
         <ResourceParams name="jdbc/someDB">
            <parameter>
                     <name>username</name>
                     <value>someuser</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                     <name>password</name>
                     <value>somepass</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                    <name>url</name>
                    <value>jdbc:sqlserver://somedb;DatabaseName=Dbname</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                     <name>driverClassName</name>
                     <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                    <name>logAbandoned</name>
                    <value>true</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                    <name>removeAbandonedTimeout</name>
                    <value>30</value>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                    <name>removeAbandoned</name>
                    <value>true</value>
            </parameter>
      </ResourceParams>
```

Comment: Are you actually using connections managed by tomcat?  It sounds more like the application code is opening connections directly on its own.

Comment: Edited with our server.xml above...

Comment: Are you using a connection pool?

Comment: Use a connection pool - c3p0 or dbcp. They have standard settings to reconnect.

Comment: Do I just add the following?
`factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`
` testOnBorrow="true"`
`validationQuery="SELECT 1"` per this page?[link](http://vigilbose.blogspot.com/2009/03/apache-commons-dbcp-and-tomcat-jdbc.html)